# Documentation Link Needed

Tags: active-directory

I'm using the following:
Dim group As New DirectoryEntry(searchResult.Path)
group.Invoke("Add",

I'm looking for the documentation for the active directory domain services object methods.  Above, I can add a user to a group, but I'm trying to find the documentation for all the methods.

My searches are not returning the results I want so I think the terminology I'm using isn't quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx

or if you're not using .Net 3.5 or greater, use System.DirectoryServices namespace
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx

You can get into non-trivial (or at least non-obvious) stuff pretty quickly.  Take a look at http://directoryprogramming.net, run by the authors of a .Net DirectoryServices book which is a great if you're just starting with directory services programming.  Their forums have many code samples and answers to detailed questions.